# Selection Sort by recursive only

Tags: java, recursion

i have got homework to implement the selection sort algorithm by using recursion (no loops allowed). I've been working for days on it but i couldn't figure it out
all i have succeeded to do is:

```
public void Sort(int[] a){
    int firstIndex=0,searchIndex=firstIndex+1,minIndex=firstIndex;
    swap(a, firstIndex, findMinIndex(a, searchIndex, minIndex));    
    }


private int findMinIndex(int[] a,int searchIndex,int minIndex){
    if(searchIndex<a.length){
        if(a[searchIndex]<a[minIndex])
            minIndex=searchIndex;
        return findMinIndex(a,searchIndex+1,minIndex);
    }
    return minIndex;            

}

private void swap(int arr[],int firstIndex,int secondIndex){
    int temp=arr[firstIndex];
    arr[firstIndex]=arr[secondIndex];
    arr[secondIndex]=temp;
}
```

how can i make the first method run as much as it needs to until the array will be sorted?

thank you guys!

Comment: Hint: If you have nested loops in the original implementation, you will probably need two recursions in the recursive version, not just one.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've found the minimum element and stuffed it into the first array position, you need to recur on the *rest* of the array.  Increment your **firstIndex** and recur until you have only one element left in the array.

Is that enough of a hint to get you moving?